# Does using uuid as part of url leaks information about the server?

Tags: python, uuid

For example, does using `uuid.uuid1()` (which uses MAC address) makes services more vulnerable? 
I just want to create a unique id for my asyn tasks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's really a problem leaking the MAC address of the server, because no one will be on the same local subnet as the server where you could do anything malicious.

But if you are concerned, why not use one of the other UUIDs in python?

- [`uuid.uuid4()`](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4) - Generate a random UUID.
- [`uuid.uuid5(namespace, name)`](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid5) - Generate a UUID based on the SHA-1 hash of a namespace identifier (which is a UUID) and a name (which is a string).

Comment: It's not like the MAC is trivially deduced from the `uuid.uuid1()` output, either; but given that there are alternatives, better to err on the side of safety.